# Use simulation model in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, model

I want to simulate a circuit that uses [this transistor](https://www.digikey.ch/product-detail/en/infineon-technologies/BFR840L3RHESDE6327XTSA1/BFR840L3RHESDE6327XTSA1CT-ND/5409978) using the popular simulator [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html). When I download the simulation model from the link I get a .zip file containing the following two files:

[image]

How can I incorporate this into my LTspice simulation?

Comment: I doubt that you downloaded a usable model. When you have the model, this question might help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229436/add-transistor-model-to-ltspice

Comment: As the filename says, you need AWR-MWO-Application to use this microwave part properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't really trust the files you find at distributors like Digikey. They are managing data for 100's of 1000's of parts, and sometimes they make mistakes. It's much better to go directly to the manufacturer website if you're looking for simulation models (or datasheets, footprint recommendations, etc.).

If you go to the [page](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf-wireless-control/rf-transistor/ultra-low-noise-sigec-transistors-for-use-up-to-12-ghz/bfr840l3rhesd) for this product at infineon.com and scroll down to the "Simulation" section, you will see they offer models for several different simulators:

[image]

It looks like Digikey offered only the second one of these files, probably meant for use with the Microwave Office simulator by AWR Software.

But if you download the file from Infineon with "SPICE" in its name, you will get a .LIB file that appears to be very basic SPICE (i.e. not using any of the commands that typically give compatibility issues between different SPICEs), and is very likely to work with LTSpice.

Comment: Digikey does not store the datafiles. They link to the OEM site AFAIK. LTspice does not have the necessary features to simulate this part

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75, Looking at the model in the LIB file from infineon.com, I don't see any features in the model that LTSpice won't be able to process.

Comment: LTspice seems to be simulating using the LIB file. At least it is not complaining about anything.

Comment: As long as you don’t complain about not being able to do Smith Charts from the EPM file.